# Getting jslider to work with Magento Go

Tags: javascript, magento-go

I just started using Magento Go. I've already discovered where to go and add css and uploaded the jslider plugin, the jquery that allows making an image slideshow. However, making use of it in a static block seems to not be showing any response compared to a regular html file. I haven't been able to get any jquery plugin working in general. How does this CMS, especially the online version, deal with making them work?

Comment: What problems are you running into other than it not working? Are the JS/CSS files for the plugin not loading when you use a static block? Are you getting JS errors when attempting to load it? Additional context is most likely going to be necessary to achieve a solution here.

Comment: Basically, the console error I get is jquery is not defined, which shouldn't happen since magento Go automatically defines the uploaded javascript files you have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Magento Go which will be closed by February 1, 2015.

Answer (score 2):

First step to get jquery working is to log into the admin then navigate to 
Design > Themes Editor > Customize (for your current theme in the top left) > Java Script Editor

You should see your files for the slider in this list. If not, upload them there. Your slider probably came with two or three js files. One will be the jquery library itself, it will probably be named something like jquery-1.6.1.min.js and the other is probably something like jquery.jslider.js. Those file names are probably a little off, since I haven't worked with that exact plugin.

Anyways, once the files are in that list you'll want to drag the one that looks like 'jquery-1.6.1.min.js' all the way to the top of the list so it gets loaded first, otherwise plugins for jquery won't be able to access it when they're loaded. Then, be sure to hit the 'Save' or 'Save and Continue Edit' button. Even if they are showing up in that list, Magento Go won't use them until you hit save.

Once that's done, go back to the frontend and check the console in your developer tools (usually F12 and click the console tab). If you type in jQuery and hit enter, it should return a function instead of being undefined.

If you're still having jQuery errors, you may need to add the line `jQuery.noConflict();` to the 'jquery-1.6.1.min.js' file and replace the one you put up earlier. Again, be sure to hit save.

Lastly, you won't be able use the `$` to reference `jQuery` since it's already being used by the Prototype JS library that Magento uses.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you upload any jquery like jquery.min.js or 1.8 version you will see the error of noConflict and also you would not be able to solve the jquery noconflict problem, cause you can not edit the code of the theme. According to me magento go is not going to be the best option for ecommerce hosting.In my case i am also having the problem in detail page when i upload any jquery in magento, it just shows the error jQuery(...).magentoZoom is not a function.